# How to animate a dojo gauge?

Tags: animation, dojo, gauge

I'm trying to animate the duration of the value change in a dojo gauge, but I think I'm missing out something, and I can't figure out what it is.

So far, I've got this code working, but the indicator just moves from one point to another, with no animation whatsoever.

```
require(["dojo/ready", "dojo/dom", "dojox/dgauges/components/black/CircularLinearGauge", "dojox/dgauges/GaugeBase"],
function(ready, dom, CircularLinearGauge, GaugeBase) {
    var gauge = new CircularLinearGauge({value:10, animationDuration:5000}, dom.byId("circularGauge"));
    setInterval(function() {
        var randomValue = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
        gauge.set("value", randomValue);
        gauge.refreshRendering();
    }, 10000);
});
```

Any help would be highly appreciated, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like its an issue with `dojox.dgauges.components.DefaultPropertiesMixin`.  If you replace the _setValueAttr function to

```
_setValueAttr: function(v) {
     this.getElement("scale").getIndicator("indicator").set("value", v);
}
```

it should animate for you.

As a side note, all the other functions in `DefaultPropertiesMixin` sets each property directly instead of using the set function.  It might be advisable to change them to use the set function instead.